# Abstract functions or function interfaces in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In a number of occasions I have a collection of functions that I'd like to implement in different ways. The most obvious example of this would be to abstract from specific databases. In an object-oriented language you would use an interface for this:

```
interface DB {
  ResultSet query(String query);
  void persist(Object o);
  ...
}
```

In speudo code I would want to do something like this:

```
(ns dbbackend)

(abstractfn query [q])
(abstractfn persist! [o])
```

And then implementations for each database:

```
(ns dbbackend.mysql :implements dbbackend)
(defn query [q] ...)
(defn persist! [o] ...)
```

It is not entirely clear to me what the best practice is to do something similar in a functional language, specifically Clojure. Should I use multi-methods for this?

Comment: multimethods look like a reasonably good match to me, perhaps the only one. But I'm no expert on Clojure so I won't volunteer a "real" answer. +1 for the good question, though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now that [version 1.1 of Clojure](http://clojure.blogspot.com/2009/12/clojure-11-release.html) has been released maybe it's time to take a look into the future.

[Datatypes](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Datatypes) and [protocols](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Protocols), which are currently only available in [the <strike>new</strike> master branch on github](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure) , might be exactly what you are looking for.

```
(defprotocol DB
  (query   [backend query])
  (persist [backend object]))

(deftype MySQLBackend []
  DB
  (query   [query] ...)
  (persist [object] ...))
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting info, but ouch, my brain hurts! Clojure seems to be growing faster than I can learn it :(

Comment: I read about those, but assumed they were mostly optimization (Clojure in Clojure etc.). They seem to fit here well too, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For pre-protocol Clojure versions:

The interface:

```
(ns dbbackend)

(defmulti query
  {:arglists '([c q])}
  suitable-dispatch-fn)

(defmulti persist!
  {:arglists '([c o])}
  suitable-dispatch-fn)
```

The implementation:

```
(ns dbbackend.mysql
  (:requires dbbackend))

(defmethod query com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
  [c q]
  ...)

(defmethod persist! com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
  [c o]
  ...)
```

The usage:

```
(ns user
  (:require dbbackend dbbackend.mysql))

(def mysql-connection (connect-to-mysql))
(query mysql-connection some-query)
```

You can find a real-world example of this approach under the hood of ClojureQL.